# OfflineAudioContext.startRendering() promise based function not working in safari

Tags: javascript, safari, cross-browser, web-audio-api, lame

OfflineAudioContext.startRendering() is working but for exporting the audiocontext object i am using lame js , so for the input for the export

```
OfflineAudioContext.startRendering().then(function(AudioBuffer){
          export(AudioBuffer);
});
function export(AudioBuffer) [
      //Export with lame library
}
```

The above snippet code is working perfect in chrome and mozilla but not working in safari .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an ordinary callback instead:

```
OfflineAudioContext.oncomplete = function(e) {
    export(e.renderedBuffer)
};
OfflineAudioContext.startRendering();
```

Comment: export function recieves the final audiobuffer as the input , with oncomplete can we fetch the final offlineaudiocontext audiobuffer ?

Comment: @AcubeTechnologies ops, let me update. The oncomplete will receive an event, but you can get the audiobuffer using e.renderedBuffer on the event.

Comment: woo it worked , Thanks friend for sharing your thoughts .

Comment: @AcubeTechnologies no problem, glad I could help